# a parameter keep being a defualt value even when i give it a real value

Tags: python, function, parameters, arguments

```
def list_manipulation(a_list,command,location,value=None):
    if value:
        if command == 'add' and location== 'beginning':
            return a_list.insert(0,value)
        elif command == 'add' and location == 'end':
            return a_list.append(value)
    elif command == 'remove'.lower() and location == 'end'.lower():
        return a_list.pop()
    elif command == 'remove'.lower() and location== 'beginning'.lower():
        return a_list.pop(0)

print(list_manipulation([23,2,7], 'add', 'end',23))
```

when i print i always get None even when i give a real value to my 'value' parameter, i tried to change the if but no luck, im going crazy !

Comment: `append` doesn't return the appended value; it always returns `None`. This doesn't have anything to do with the value of `value`.

Comment: Why do you use `.lower()`? Your strings are already lowercase. I think you mean `command.lower() == 'remove'`

Comment: List methods "insert" and "append" always return "None".